# How to create tableview in UITableViewCell? with expandable function

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have created `UITableView` 1, and then I have created `UITableView` 2 in `UITableViewCell` `UITableView` 1, `UITableView` 1 have function expandable also `UITableView` 2.

I have done use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for make cell `UITableView` 2 dynamic when i expand row of `UITableView` 2.

but i have struggle with that, anyone can give me solution? or best practice for my cases?

Comment: use section and rows. So tableview section will have the functionality to show number of rows.

Comment: tableview inside tableview this is very difficult case Use section header instead.  I have tried almost all the possible solutions. but none of are working correctly then I have to use hack which some how working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031969/tableview-automatic-dimension-tableview-inside-tableview/50940677#50940677

Comment: Do you want the tableview2 height should be its content size when it is expanded?